# My app is not shown in market of my device?

Tags: android, google-play

I created on application with following properties in Manifest file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.cpt.ViddyGo"
      android:versionCode="2"
      android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="7" />

    .......
    ........
    ....

<supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"        
        />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />

</manifest>
```

Some the device it shows app in market, download & install also works fine. But in in my device with android 2.2.1 OS Samsung pop it will shows "your deive is not compatible for this item”.

I checked all permission , screen size ,features and SDK , all are supported in my device but it is not shown up in market.

If any one knows the solution, please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Check device listing in your publisher account and check whether samsung pop is available there?

Answer (score 0):

check Whether Samsung pop is in supported device for android market as per below links.

Missing devices on the Android Market website

http://support.google.com/androidmarket/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1141080

Supported Devices

http://support.google.com/androidmarket/bin/answer.py?answer=1727131#S